# How to copy attached documents between lists?

Tags: list, custom-list

I have a custom list and I want to copy attached documents to another custom list. How can I do this using workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some good link:

http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/01/02/sharepoint-designer-copy-list-item-workflow-activity-does-not-copy-all-fields.aspx

http://slingeronline.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/tweaking-copy-list-item-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Maria. I did this through item copy. It copies all list items, including attached documents.